# Como voltar ao topo de um Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, material-design

Seguindo os padrões do Material design, ao clicar em um botão de um Bottom Navigation que já está ativo, a activity deve [rolar até o topo](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)
Eu tenho um FrameLayout com CoordinatorLayout, que por sua vez, tem um RecyclerView(uma lista de elementos). Minha intenção é fazer a activity rolar até o topo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode, ao clicar no botão com `onClick`, usar o método `scrollToPositionWithOffset` da classe `LinearLayoutManager`, passando como parâmetro a posição `0,0`. Veja:

```
lManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
```

Então ficaria desta forma:

```
bottonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        LinearLayoutManager lManager = (LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView
                .getLayoutManager();
        lManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
    }
});
```

Referência a [essa resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26876044/2570426).